# Refresh the parent page and close the child using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to capture web cam images and save them in the database. It works properly.
There are two web pages. When a button clicked in the Page1, it opens a popup (Page2) for capture the image.

**Page1**

[image]

**Page2**

[image]

After clicking the submit button, it saves the image in the database by UploadPic() function and closes itself. I want to reload the Page1 again to show the 
last captured image within it. It reloads, but it executes the button click event automatically and open the popup again. I want to stop that. I think the problem is
within the UploadPic() function.

```
        function UploadPic() {
        debugger;
        // generate the image data
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        // Sending the image data to Server
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "baseimg.aspx",
            data: { imgBase64: dataURL },
            success: function () {
                alert("Done, Picture Uploaded.");
                window.opener.location.reload(true); // reloading Parent page
                window.close();
                window.opener.setVal(1);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: In page 1 what type of button are you using? What Prog.language are you using?

Comment: It's just an asp button. This is the code behind for button click event.

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string url = "/WebCam/Captureimage.aspx";
 string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=900,height=460,left=100,top=100,resizable=no');";
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
}

Comment: would you mind to try my answer?

Comment: With Response.Redirect("page1.aspx") , it loads the page1 within the popup. But I want to close the popup and reload the Page1

Comment: How about put this in the body of your page 2 `<body onunload="window.opener.document.location.href='yourparentpage.aspx;">`

Comment: if this wont work try my updated answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about ASP, but this is what I have found.

Try this to your submit button:

```
protected void yoursavebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UploadPic();
    Response.Redirect("page1.aspx");
}
```

Or Put this to your child page(Page 2) `<body onunload="opener.location=opener.location;">`

Comment: @G.Madri Glad to help! You need to treat me for that. :D

Comment: Maybe I am just quicker to find a solution. :D Cheers mate!